# Similar artists to rising crimson?

Tags: rock, electronic-music, jazz, similar-artists, hip-hop

So, as a composer I usually have musical influences which I'm unaware of but realise years later. I was hoping someone could resonate with the musical inspiration seized me and lasted an album.

Who are some similar artists I can listen to?

[Rising Crimson](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/sets/rising-crimson) - The Album

1. [How it's done](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/how-its-done-1)  - Electro?
2. [Reawaken](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/reawaken-1?in=an_ant_sax/sets/rising-crimson)  - Rock?
3. [Superstep](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/superstep?in=an_ant_sax/sets/rising-crimson)  -Rock?
4. [Lambaste](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/lambaste?in=an_ant_sax/sets/rising-crimson)  - Hiphop?
5. [Undefeated](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/undefeated?in=an_ant_sax/sets/rising-crimson) - Rock?
6. [Upbeatz](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/world-is-not-enough?in=an_ant_sax/sets/rising-crimson)  - Jrock?
7. [World Is Not Enough](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/sets/rising-crimson)  - Pop/PopRock?
8. [Against The Heavens](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/against-the-heavens?in=an_ant_sax/sets/rising-crimson)  - Rock?
9. [Encore](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/encore?in=an_ant_sax/sets/rising-crimson)  - ???
10. [Dusk and Dawn](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/dusk-and-dawn?in=an_ant_sax/sets/rising-crimson) - JazzRock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I listened to the piece *World Is Not Enough*. It reminds me of 90s "industrial rock". Groups like Ministry, Nine Inch Nails, and some of the harder stuff from Aphex Twin (eg. [Bucephalus Bouncing Ball](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQdhzQkddCc)). Also the layering of rhythms reminds me of "[Afrobeat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFaqJC_tXP8&list=PLl8UdbmjwcGxuhJUxj6Ph0XRV338bFSU3)" and the African rhythms of [Art Blakey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6u5WZpSc38g&list=PLyHn3f7-9IUKa7Q8_Ja8H-WyX0brISR-U&index=2).

I think adding vocals would be good, otherwise the loops can start to feel repetitive. Another option would be to vary the rhythms. If you listen to the Aphex Twin song, it sounds like loops at first but if you listen more closely it changes every time.